# Find memory leaks (ever-increasing value)

Tags: r, time-series

I need to analyze counter Memory Pool / Nonpaged GBytes. If it increases over time - memory leak is suspected. That's situation I need to recognize.

The problem, Value is not always increasing, it could be constant on some periods, decrease a little bit but trend should be - up. Also PC could be restarted, that case Value will go down and continue increasing from that point.

That's how that data looks on real example if memory leak happens:

[image]

That's how it looks if not:

[image]

That's my sample data.

How to find is it increasing or not? Any help will be appreciated.

```
data <- data.frame ( id = 1:22,
                    datetime = seq(
                      as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:00:00"),
                      as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:05:15"),
                      "15 sec"),
                      Value = c(1,2,3,4,3,5,6,6,5,10,8,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,5,7,9)
                    )
```

Comment: split time series on 0 (probable restart) and check if they have a positive trend. Good book on time series https://otexts.com/fpp2/

Comment: I don't think restart will be 0. It will be low but not 0. Anyway, how to find a trend? Is there any helpful functions in R?

Comment: Did you have a look at the proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to detect a trend is to follow-up the rolling average of the slope:

```
# Example data
n <- 1e3
slope <- .01
data <- c(runif(n,min=0.15,max=0.25) , ((1:n) * slope + runif(n,min=0.15,max=0.25)))
plot(data)
```

[image]

Rolling average of `diff` to estimate the slope change:

```
plot(zoo::rollmean(diff(data),50))
```

[image]
You can put a threshold to detect a drift (slope being near zero if there's no drift)

For live data, you could use exponentialy weighted moving average which can be easily updated after each new data point :

```
rollmean <- 0
alpha <- .05

for (i in 2:length(data)) {
  rollmean[i] <- (1-alpha) * rollmean[i-1] + (data[i]-data[i-1])*alpha
}
plot(rollmean)
```

[image]

In both cases, you'll need to tune the parameters to find the correct window & threshold.

In the example you provided :

- maximum slope in normal situation over 2 days is below 0.025Gb/day
- slope during drift is ~0.1Gb/day

One possibility would be a moving average of `diff` over 2 days, with a detection threshold of 0.05Gb/day.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the summary and slope of the linear model fitted to that data:

```
summary(lm(data$Value~as.numeric(data$datetime-data$datetime[1])))
# Result:
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4760 -1.7892 -0.2753  1.3251  5.7916 

Coefficients:
                                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                                  3.003953   1.056954   2.842   0.0101 *
as.numeric(data$datetime - data$datetime[1]) 0.008922   0.005744   1.553   0.1360  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.564 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1076,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.06303 
F-statistic: 2.413 on 1 and 20 DF,  p-value: 0.136
```

Or you can simply look at the correlation of the two variables to see if there is a strong positive correlation (there isn't)

```
cor(data$Value,as.numeric(data$datetime-data$datetime[1]))
# Result:
[1] 0.3280922
```

Comment: I like the correlation method. It works for my cases and it's very simple. But sometimes it's not very clear why correlation coefficient is so small  or big. Is it possible to show correlation for every point of plot to see which intervals go down and which go up?